# JavaScript 2D array, if input RegEx match col1 , return col2

Tags: javascript, arrays, chatbot

I trying to set up a chatbot which when user input match some word, then will response accordingly.

this works

```
  var input = "i love you";
  
  if(/.*cute.*/.test(input)) { alert("Aw.... so sweet");}
  if(/.*love.*/.test(input)) { alert("Love you too");}

//result "Love you too"
```

However, how can I put the data in an array and still make it works?

example:

```
var queryResponse = [ ["cute","Aw.... so sweet"],
                      ["love","Love you too"] ];
```

How do I modify this line?

```
 if(/.*  (what should i insert here?) .*/.test(input)) { alert(So that the response appear here?);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index of each keys and value should match

```
var keys=['cute','love'];
var values= ['so cute', 'i love you'];
        
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length ; i++){
        
   let re = new RegExp(`.*${keys[i]}*.`);
    
   if(re.test(input){
        alert(values[i]);
        break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var regexArray =  [ ["cute","Aw.... so sweet"],["love","Love you too"] ]
    
    for(var i = 0; i < regexArray.length ; i++){
    
    let re = new RegExp(`.*${regexArray[i][0]}*.`);

    if(re.test(input){
    alert(regexArray[i][1]);
    break;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works nicely. How do I add the name: value:  thing in my current array? my current array is plain like this [ ["cute","Aw.... so sweet"],["love","Love you too"] ].

Comment: I have changed my solution according your requirement

Comment: may i know why it is .... RegExp(`.*${regexArray[i][0]}*.`)... and not RegExp(`.*${regexArray[i][0]}.*`)... , and also is there a way to use forEach in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const queryResponseMap = new Map([
  ["cute", "Aw.... so sweet"],
  ["love", "Love you too"]
]);

function getResponse(query) {
  const iterator = queryResponseMap.entries();
  let result = iterator.next();

  while (!result.done) {
    const [key, val] = result.value;

    if (new RegExp(`.*${key}*.`).test(query)) {
      return val;
    }

    result = iterator.next();
  }

  return null;
}

console.log(getResponse("Hi love"));
console.log(getResponse("You're cute"));
```

Comment: may i know why it is ....  RegExp(`.*${key}*.`)... and not RegExp(`.*${key}.*`)...